# Login User To Magento Via OpenID

Tags: php, magento, openid

If I have already authenticated a user via OpenID, and they are redirected back to Magento, how do I log them in automatically?  All I have is their email.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate. Are you write your own module which should login user via Open ID?

Comment: Yes, I am writing my own module.

Comment: Ok, so you have callback page to which user will be redirected by open id provider after login. On this page you have user email and auth token from open id provider. You need additional table with 2 columns - auth token and user id. Your module should look into this table and if token is found there - log user in, otherwise create new customer. Do you know how to login customer in and create new customer using Mage_Customer_Model_Customer model?

Comment: No.  That is the part I do not know.  I know how to create the customer, but I don't know how to log in the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is answer to question how to login customer in, not to initial big question. I decided to write it here because code formatting is absent in comments.

```
// $login here is customer email
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
    ->loadByEmail($login);

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
    ->renewSession();

// now redirect user to home page or do something else what you need
```

Comment: worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!  You've saved me hours of work!